# loop through all files in a folder

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I'm writing a script to get all files within a folder(including sub-folder):

```
#!/bin/bash
function loop() {
files=`ls -1Fd $1`
echo "$files" |
while IFS= read -r file; do
    if [[ "$file" == */ ]]; then
        loop "$file*"
    else
        echo "$file"
    fi
done
}
loop "$PWD/*"
```

I tried to test the script in this way:

```
#create folders and files
mkdir test\ folder && mkdir test\ folder/test\ subfolder && touch test\ folder/test\ subfolder/test\ file && cd test\ folder

#execute the script
~/path_to_the_script/test.sh
```

But it doesn't work, here is the error:

```
ls: cannot access /home/user/Documents/test: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access folder/*: No such file or directory
```

How to modify the script to achieve it?

Comment: I sort of don't understand what you are trying to do. Listing files in directory and subdirectory can be done with `find . -type f` already

Comment: @Serg Yes, you're right. But I'm learning linux script, and I want to know how to do this with a script.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why are you going so much out of way, just keep it simple

```
#!/bin/bash
function loop() { 
    for i in "$1"/*
    do
        if [ -d "$i" ]; then
            loop "$i"
        elif [ -e "$i" ]; then
            echo $i
        else
            echo "$i"" - Folder Empty"
        fi
    done
}
loop "$PWD"
```

Hope that helps ;)

Comment: Thank you. But I'm confused. I think `for i in "$1"/*` loops according to the value of `IFS`, and the default `IFS` contains white space, so if the file name contains white space, `$1` will be split into multiple parts. For example, if `"$PWD"` is `test folder`, `$i` should be `test` and `folder`. But in fact, this is not the case. the script works very well. Why? Did I miss anything?

Comment: Its the quotes, when you put `$i` within quotes like this `"$i"` it encapsulates the full path including white spaces. Try putting an echo before and after and using it with and without quotes , that will clarify it. Hope that helps ;)

Comment: @MarkZar To add more,  same will be the case with `"$1"/*`, if you use `$1/*` instead of it you will get same error you mentioned.

Answer (score 6):

First of all, [don't parse `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). Now, the reason your script fails is because you are passing `"$PWD/*"`. Because that's qupted, it will be expanded before it's passed to your function to `/path/to/dir/*` and since there is no file named `*` in your `PWD`, it fails.

However, even if it worked, that would have gotten you into an infinite loop.

What you are looking for is:

```
#!/bin/bash

function loop() {
    ## Do nothing if * doesn't match anything.
    ## This is needed for empty directories, otherwise
    ## "foo/*" expands to the literal string "foo/*"/
    shopt -s nullglob

    for file in $1
    do
    ## If $file is a directory
    if [ -d "$file" ]
    then
            echo "looping for $file"
        loop "$file/*"
    else
            echo "$file"
    fi
    done
}
loop "$PWD/*"
```

That, however, will fail if your `PWD` contains any whitespace characters. A safer way is:

```
#!/bin/bash

function loop() {
    ## Do nothing if * doesn't match anything.
    ## This is needed for empty directories, otherwise
    ## "foo/*" expands to the literal string "foo/*"/
    shopt -s nullglob

    ## Make ** recurse into subdirectories
    shopt -s globstar

    for file in "$@"/**
    do
    ## If $file is a file
    if [ -f "$file" ]
    then
        echo "$file"
    fi
    done
}
loop "$PWD"
```

Comment: +1 for `shopt -s nullglob`!